# Does java 8 having any alternative of normal while loop?

Tags: java

I need a while loop alternative in Java 8, can we do that via stream?

Using while loop, we can get string token by below code

```java
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer=new StringTokenizer("this is a text string"," ");
while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
System.out.println(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

But using stream, how can we achieve it?
please suggest

Comment: Split your string into array of elements and use it to generate stream (there are few options for that described in many tutorials).

Comment: @OleV.V. The [Pattern.splitAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method lends itself to Stream use even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
   Collections.list(new StringTokenizer("this is a text string", " ")).stream()
            .map(token -> (String) token)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
this
is
a
text
string
```

one more sample

```
    List<String> collect = Collections.list(new StringTokenizer("this is a text string", " ")).stream()
            .map(token -> (String) token)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
```

Output:

```
[this, is, a, text, string]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `String#split` here with a stream:

```
String input = "this is a text string";
Arrays.stream(input.split("\\s+"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments `StringTokenizer` is an old class. As an alternative you could simply use [`String::split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method and then make a `Stream` out of returned array :

```
String text = "this is a text string";
Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

@VGR is perfectly right in the comment, since Java 8 (that is, since the introduction of streams), the `Pattern` class has been fitted with a `splitAsStream` method that is exactly right for getting a stream of the words of your string. For exmaple:

```
    Pattern delimiterPattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
    String originalString = "this is a text string";
    List<String> collect = delimiterPattern.splitAsStream(originalString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
```

Output:

> [this, is, a, text, string]

Or if you just want the stream elements printed as in your question:

```
    delimiterPattern.splitAsStream(originalString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

> ```
> this
> is
> a
> text
> string
> ```

The documentation says:

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of
>   `String` or the java.util.regex package instead.

The latter is what this answer does.

**Documentation links:**

- [`Pattern.splitAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).
- [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)